# Shortcut to creating an adjacency matrix

Tags: python, adjacency-matrix, minimum-spanning-tree

I need a short and sweet version of the python code I wrote. So basically what I have is a text file with values such as below:

```
x
a b c
d e f
```

First line is the number of nodes. From second line, the values are read into NODE1, NODE2, Weight. I am taking these values and creating an adjacency matrix out of it. This will be an undirected graph so matrix[u][v] will equal matrix[v][u].
This is the code I have :

```
with open(filename, 'r') as textfile:
            firstLine = int(textfile.readline())
            for line in textfile:
                a, b, c = line.split()
                a = int(a)
                b = int(b)
                c = float(c)
                graph[a][b] = graph[b][a] = c
```

Now I need to populate the diagonals as zero, and other unassigned indices to infinity.

Comment: do you mean diagonals zero, and other unassigned indices to infinity?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the confusion..

Comment: I don't see anything that can be dramatically improved in your code. Perhaps use `next(textfile)` instead of `textfile.readline()`, but that's pretty minor.

Comment: Added answer. I believe this is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(filename, 'r') as textfile:
    file_lines = text_file.readlines()

    # Initialize graph with -1 value, i.e. path do not exists representing infinite
    # Note: If negative weight is allowed, use the value which you want to symbolize infinte
    total_node = int(file_lines[0])
    my_graph = [[-1]*total_node]*total_node

    # Update weight based on available path
    for line in file_lines[1:]:
        s = line.split()
        u, v, w = int(s[0]), int(s[1]), float(s[2])
        my_graph[u][v] = my_graph[v][u] = w

    # Update diagonals to zero
    for i in range(total_node):
        my_graph[i][i] = my_graph[i][total_node - (i+1)] = 0
```

Comment: `w` should be a float.

Comment: :-) Great. But `u, v` should still be ints.

Comment: User has not mentioned about the kind of data he is holding. I am changing it back to `int` and will let him modify based on what he want. There is no point in making assumptions :)

Comment: No, not quite - check his code, it's `int, int, float`. Modified it for you. Hope you don't mind (cancel the edit if you do).

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `a = int(a), b = int(b), c = float(c)` part of the question. But I am making that change in other way. Hope you won't mind

Comment: It's your answer - feel free to write what you want in it. All the best.

Comment: I was thinking whether it will be a nice to do it within list comprehension as a generic approach or not. But in order to prevent the extra overhead and complexity, I will keep your answer as it is.

Comment: Well, now I'm partial to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure simpler, but with numpy reshape you can create the default matrix before you populate with the weights without explicit loops.  Here `n` is the size.

```
In [20]: n=4; np.reshape(np.array(([0]+[float("inf")]*n)*(n-1)+[0]),[n,n])
Out[20]:
array([[  0.,  inf,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,   0.,  inf,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,   0.,  inf],
       [ inf,  inf,  inf,   0.]])
```